# Update Query in VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds = executeCommand("update travels set  travelpackageid='" & txtCMUser.Text & "' , no_of_person='" & txtMem.Text & "', book_date='" & txtArrivalv.Text & "',type_of_vechile='" & DropDownListTypevechile.Text & "',travel_package='" & DropDownListPackages.Text & "' where cust_id =")
```

I have use this query in updating my travels table but I get following error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ enough said. Oh, and where are you putting this code? Which event? Can you post the surrounding code as well?

Comment: As Eugene indicates in his answer, you should protect against SQL Injection by using parameters (eg., SqlParameter), rather than building a command string at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You have a "<" character in one of the input strings.

On a side note, I hope you are sanitizing your input. Otherwise, [bad things](http://xkcd.com/327/) may happen :)